# How to get the underlying network interface used by a VPN connection in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, network-interface, virtual-network-interface

The closest thing to a solution I've found is using Get-NetConnectionProfile to return all active interfaces, which works fine when there's only an active physical interface and the VPN itself. However, this would not work if the user's machine has 2 active physical interfaces (e.g Wi-Fi + Ethernet) along with the VPN.

[image: Get-NetConnectionProfile]

Ideally, I'd like a solution that works similarly to "ifconfig -v" in MacOS, which tells you the effective interface for a virtual interface:

[image: ifconfig -v]

Comment: I'm looking for a way to accomplish this programmatically, so yes I would consider it a programming question. That's why I'm showing the output of ifconfig in Mac instead of whatever the GUI equivalent of that information is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems there is no sure-fire way to get the underlying physical adapter for a VPN using a Windows API. Short of involving a packet sniffer such as Wireshark, the best solution I found involves parsing the output of two PowerShell commands: Get-NetAdapter and Get-NetRoute.

With the information from these commands, I can know which interfaces are virtual and which ones are physical, and I can rank the physical interfaces by 3 different criteria (in case of tie, we move on to the next criteria):

1. Sorting the physical interfaces by the interface metric + the route metric to the default gateway (0.0.0.0).
2. Wired connections over wireless ones (PhysicalMediaType=802.3).
3. Prioritizing faster adapters.

With this logic all the VPNs I tested appear to reflect the expected network interface, although some VPNs let you force traffic through a particular physical adapter in which case obviously this all goes out the window.

Answer (score 0):

First,

You can install `wireshark` or some other traffic monitoring tool and capture the relevant packets (filtering using openvVPN protocol or port etc.)

Second,

As far as I know there is no hard linking between the virtual network interface and the regular (ethernet, WIFI etc.) interface, at least not in OpenVPN (there are diffrent VPN protocols). The openVPN packets will be routed to the remote server using you OS routing table.

This way if your ethernet interface is your primary default gateway, and it gets unplugged, your VPN service will be able to recover, since it will have a route to your remote VPN-server address using your WIFI interface.

Comment: Also it might be usefull to read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes In order to understand how the Os handels the situation when there are multiple default gateways

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It seems odd to me that Mac has such a relatively simple solution when compared to Windows. I had already read the metrics article you mentioned, and my current solution for this problem is replicating Windows' logic to decide which is the "best" physical adapter and assuming that's the one the VPN will use. However, I was hoping there was some other OS API I could've used to guarantee I'd get the correct underlying interface without having to involve external programs such as Wireshark.

Comment: Forgot to add an important detail. My original theory was pretty much the same as yours, the underlying physical interface for a VPN would be chosen the same way an adapter is chosen via the routing tables. However, that does not seem to be the case in general. Hotspot VPN, for example, actually binds to a physical interface and always uses it instead of delegating the routing to Windows.

Comment: Does it use openVPN? can you please add your config file, remove all the keys and certs and any other sensitive data before.

Comment: HotspotVPN uses its own protocol AFAIK, it's a free VPN so you can simply download and try it with the default settings.

Comment: Seems like hostspot shield vpn uses `Hydra` by defaul. But supports many other protocols. https://support.hotspotshield.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041911131-Which-VPN-protocol-should-I-choose-

Comment: The real problem is I have no control over which VPN is in use. The program I'm developing will be installed on millions of machines and thus needs to account for the most edge cases possible.